# CSS position:sticky weird behavior in different browsers depending on overflow value of "html" and "body" tag

Tags: html, css, sticky

this happened while working on a specific project. I had a `div` with following css:

```css
div.my-div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
}
```

(other styles applying to it as well, none affecting any css values related to `position: sticky`).

this div would become sticky when the page scrolled and it reached top of the viewport, but with scrolling a bit more would go away as if another sticky element was replacing it. for testing purposes, I commented out all other elements in the page and only inserted a dummy div with sufficient height to enable scrolling, and the behavior stayed the same.

this behavior was also limited to Chrome and Firefox (both latest version) and I could not replicate it in Safari. surprisingly, this css snippet fixed the issue:

```css
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

setting `overflow-x` to `hidden` only on `body` or `html` didn't work, and this fix caused other Safari-only scrolling-related issues.

I ended up fixing the problem by changing the value of `overflow-x` on `html` and `body` using JS depending on the browser being Safari or not. however, I feel generally uncomfortable with this solution. anyone else had similar issues? any ideas on what might be causing this and are there any solutions to this not involving JS snippets detecting whether it is Safari or not?

Comment: share full code that reproduce the behavior

Comment: also not the with safari you need the prefix : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: yeah there is this fella taking care of vendor prefixes, and also the full code reproducing it currently is a little bit too much, asides from legal restrictions on sharing it. I will try later to see if I can capture the same issue with a minimal code and share if I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

position **sticky** is still not widely/fully supported in all browsers.

> A parent with overflow set to auto will prevent position: sticky from working in Safari
>
> Firefox 58 & below, Chrome 63 & below and Safari 7 & below do not appear to support sticky table headers.

are known issues, you can see how widely supported it is and current issues on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)

There are polyfills available such as [stickfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) but even these have their limitations.
I've used [Stickybits](https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/) in the past & have been pleasantly supprised if you want to check it out.

`stickybits('[your-sticky-selector]')`

Comment: well the issue did not match any of those mentioned [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), thats why I couldn't pin it down without playing around (still I just found a random work-around). and yes I've read good things about Stickybits as well, but since it is a marginal functional requirement I would prefer not adding an extra JS library for it, but thanks for the suggestion.